# geodatabase/workspace content viewer control

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, c#

I'm in the process of developing a windows form (desktop) app that will have the ability to display content from user-provided personal geodatabases (.mbd files). I want to create a custom control that will display in some part (a tree view?) all available databases, and in another part (list view?) will display the contents of the selected database. And by content I mean, to display a selectable icon for each dataset in the db.

My question is, is there something similar already implemented?

PS Im using ArcObjects 10, C# 4

Comment: You mean something like ArcCatalog, but easir to use?

Comment: I mean, any kind of geodatabase-enabled control I can attach to my form, allowing user to select from a set of datasets to work with.

Comment: This link is kind of what I think you are looking for, however it is not implemented in a windows form.  http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/extendingarcobjects/ch04/CatalogView.htm

Comment: Can the app depend on a desktop license?  Or is it restricted to an Engine license?

Comment: If you are still hoping for an Answer to this Question would you be able to edit answers to the last couple of Comments into it, please>  Also, be sure to let us know if 10.0 is still the target version.